# Multiplication of "double" values in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to multiply two sparse matrices in spark using scala. I am passing these matrices in form of arguments and storing result in another argument. 
Matrices are text files where each matrix element is represented by as: row, column, element.

I am not able to multiply two Double values in Scala.

```
object MultiplySpark {
    def main(args: Array[ String ]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Multiply")
        conf.setMaster("local[2]")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        val M = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(entry => {
        val rec = entry.split(",")
        val row = rec(0).toInt
        val column = rec(1).toInt
        val value = rec(2).toDouble

        for {pointer <-1 until rec.length} yield ((row,column),value)
        })

            val N = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(entry => {
        val rec = entry.split(",")
        val row = rec(0).toInt
        val column = rec(1).toInt
        val value = rec(2).toDouble

        for {pointer <-1 until rec.length} yield ((row,column),value)
        })


         val Mmap = M.map( e => (e._2,e))
     val Nmap = N.map( d => (d._2,d))

     val MNjoin = Mmap.join(Nmap).map{ case (k,(e,d)) => e._2.toDouble+","+d._2.toDouble }

    val result = MNjoin.reduceByKey( (a,b) => a*b)
  .map(entry => {
    ((entry._1._1, entry._1._2), entry._2)
  })
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

  result.saveAsTextFile(args(2))
  sc.stop()
```

How can I multiply double values in Scala?
Please note:
I tried `a.toDouble * b.toDouble`

Error is: Value * is not a member of Double Double

[image]

Comment: You should post the actual compilation error, not just "gives error".

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question. I have now modified my question with error. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `reduceByKey` would work if you had `RDD[((Int, Int), Double)]` (or `RDD[(SomeType, Double)]` more generally) and `join` gives you `RDD[((Int, Int), (Double, Double))]`. So you are trying to multiply pairs `(Double, Double)`, not `Double`s.